# Java Swing Projects/Library/Templates Repository

Tags: java, swing

Does anyone know of any repositories that keeps a list of various Java Swing projects/plugins?

Answer (score 2):

There is [SwingX](http://java.net/projects/swingx) but I'm not sure on how active this is anymore.

Oracle is trying to push [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/) as the new technology for Java GUI development and is not investing heavily into Swing anymore.

Comment: SwingX is active enough, as in alive and kicking :-) Completely detached from snoracle since ages - new sponsors welcome! Release 1.6.3 in the trenches, hampered by last-minute problems with gui builders: http://www.java.net/forum/topic/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/swinglabs/windowbuilder-woes-swingx-163 - for speedup of analysing the problem, feedback (esp. testing with Netbeans) wanted

Comment: @mKorbel sorry, don't understand what you mean - all tests are available along with the sources (checkout from svn or download the appropriate maven artefact). What I meant is that - as mentioned in the forum thread I referenced - Karl is looking for testers which try out the release candidate against Netbeans guibuilder. If that turns out to be working, we'll point fingers to Eclipse WindowBuilder and release as-is :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can check java.net open-source projects out, I've seen great projects there myself : http://www.java.net/projects/community/138